# How to inject DI container into a controller?

Tags: php

I have successfuly installed Router using [PHP-DI](http://php-di.org/). 
There is some simple [app example](https://github.com/kevinsmith/no-framework) based on the [article](https://kevinsmith.io/modern-php-without-a-framework).

There are 2 files: index.php and controller.php.  I want to use $container from controller. However, I have no idea how to inject it?

```
// index.php 

use... 
require_once... 

$containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder(); 
.... 
$container = $containerBuilder->build(); // I succesfuilly build a container here with all needed definitions, including Database, Classes and so on. 

$routes = simpleDispatcher(function (RouteCollector $r) {
    $r->get('/hello', Controller::class);
});
$middlewareQueue[] = new FastRoute($routes);
$middlewareQueue[] = new RequestHandler($container);

$requestHandler = new Relay($middlewareQueue);
$response = $requestHandler->handle(ServerRequestFactory::fromGlobals());

$emitter = new SapiEmitter();
return $emitter->emit($response);
```

So the code just receive Response from the dispatcher and pass it off to the emitter.

```
namespace ExampleApp;
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface;

class Controller
{
    private $foo;
    private $response;

    public function __construct(
        string $foo,
        ResponseInterface $response
    ) {
        $this->foo = $foo;
        $this->response = $response;
    }

    public function __invoke(): ResponseInterface
    {
        $response = $this->response->withHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
        $response->getBody()
            ->write("<html><head></head><body>Hello, {$this->foo} world!</body></html>");

        return $response;
    }
}
```

Now I want to add logic into Controller based on my $container: database, logger and so on. I want somehow to use  $container instance which was created in index.php. I have tried a lot of ways, but nothing works proper.